# Low pressure in bathroom hot water faucet

Tags: bathroom

The hot water pressure is low in tub and kitchen sink.   The stem and cartridge have been changed but the water pressure is still low.   This is a delta stem and cartridge.

Comment: check the documentation for the existence of a "heat adjustment ring" which my limit the hot water flow for safety.

Comment: if it's both tub and sink, it isn't the internals of the faucets.  Is this a new problem?

Comment: When was the last time your hot water tank was cleaned? What type of water system, city, well, etc? Be sure the airerators are clean in both sinks. Can you post a picture of the valves.

Comment: The water pressure should be the same as your cold water pressure.  What is that one ? You did all you can think about, and not giving us any information on where the hot water comes from is missing to help you.

Comment: The cartridges only regulate the Flow, not the pressure.